Stop a Azure Function Queue Trigger using the ArmClient
Is it possible to stop a Queue Trigger inside an Azure Function App using the ArmClient library?  I have been through all the documentation, and have not been able to find a suitable method.
If no, is there another way to do this in C#?

Add "AzureWebJobs.QueueTrigger.Disabled": true app setting in the function app's configuration. You can also stop the function using command Stop-AzFunctionApp -Name MyAppName -ResourceGroupName MyResourceGroupName -Force

Check if below solution helps @WilliamTroup.

To disable a particular Azure function, add the application setting "AzureWebJobs.<FunctionName>.Disabled": true under Function App=>Environment Variables=>App Settings, refer MSDOC.

Portal:
You can see the status Disabled as below.

To disable the function locally, add the setting AzureWebJobs.<FunctionName>.Disabled in local.settings.json:
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
    "connectionString": "<Storage_connection_string>",
    "AzureWebJobs.<FunctionName>.Disabled": true
  }
}

Console Output:

You can use the below PowerShell command to stop the functionapp:
Stop-AzFunctionApp -Name MyAppName -ResourceGroupName MyResourceGroupName -Force


